# subprocess.Popen does not store exception to the errorfile

Tags: python, popen

I was trying to execute a python script from another python script, using subprocess.Popen. My command was:

```
outf = open('out.txt','w+')
errf = open('err.txt','w+')
p = subprocess.Popen([cmd],stdin=inf,stdout=outf,stderr=errf,shell=True)
```

all the required are defined previously. This has no problem for piping to the stdout file. But, when there are errors in the python script, it exits with an error. That error is neither stored in the stdout file nor the stderr file. What should I do to this?

I get that the file exited because of an error, by using `p.returncode`. But how do I get the error traceback?

Comment: please provide more context. how do you initialize `errf`?

Comment: @Pavel: Added. And there is no problem with this initialization,since if it is executed without errors,the output is stored in out.txt

Comment: Are you closing the files properly? You should that you `open` the files, but not that you `close` them.

Comment: @Bakuriu Good idea, but I did not have to close the files below in my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry the mistake was mine.. I opened the files with 'w+' permissions and did a read on that file pointer. So I did not get any data displayed. I closed it and opened with read permission and then read the contents and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$ cat pytest1.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python

for i in ranger(5):
    print "hi"

>>> outf = open('out.txt','w+')
>>> errf = open('err.txt','w+')
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(["./pytest1.py"],stdout=outf,stderr=errf,shell=True)
>>> a,b = p.communicate()
>>> p.returncode
1
>>> a
>>> b
```

You can also use:

```
>>> p = subprocess.Popen("./pytest1.py",stdout=outf,stderr=errf,shell=True)
```

The error is populated in `err.txt`

```
$ cat out.txt
$ cat err.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pytest1.py", line 3, in <module>
    for i in ranger(5):
NameError: name 'ranger' is not defined
```